# How can I mount configuration file and other files on AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-fargate

I am trying to run the [Telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/) as a docker container on AWS fargate.
I have created the Telegraf image file using Dockerfile and built the image and pushed it to ECR.
Now, I am trying to run this image on AWS fargate.

The main challenge I facing is how to mount the configuration (telegraf.conf) file to the container
which required by container to run it.
I tried following this https://kichik.com/2020/09/10/mounting-configuration-files-in-fargate/ blog by spinning two containers but I have more files that I am passing to the telegraf.conf file.
Fargate provides two options to mount files using the Bind mount and EFS. I am trying to use Bind Mount but I am not sure how to provide the configuration files or mount them.
I am showing below how I run the telegraf container using docker-compose.

```
telegraf1:
    image: telegraf:1.20.0
    container_name: telegraf
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - influxdb
    networks:
      - analytics
    volumes:
      - /mnt/telegraf/:/var/lib/telegraf
      - ./etc/telegraf/:/etc/telegraf/
    env_file:
      - secrets.env
    environment:
        INFLUXDB_URL: http://influxdb:8086
    command:
        --config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
        --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
    links:
      - influxdb
```

Now I want to achieve same using AWS fargate but not sure how to provide the volume mount on AWS fargate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind mount on Fargate is good for sharing a folder between multiple containers in a single task, but I'm not aware of any way to load external configuration files in Fargate bind mounts, other than running a sidecar container to download those from S3 on task startup.

I generally see EFS used for mounting a folder with configuration files in Fargate.

Comment: if helpful, you can load an .env file